# Testing Thinking Sphinx with acts_as_taggable_on Querying Against Erroneous Table Names

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thinking-sphinx, acts-as-taggable-on

To begin with, the production side of things works just fine, it's only when I run the tests that errors arise.

As stated in the title, I am using Thinking Sphinx with the acts_as_taggle gem. Here are some snippets from the model I am using:

```
class Special < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_taggable
  acts_as_taggable_on :cuisines, :meals

  ...

  define_index do
    ...
    indexes cuisine_taggings.tag(:name), :as => :cuisine_tags, :facet => true
    indexes meal_taggings.tag(:name), :as => :meal_tags
    ...
  end

  ...

end
```

The search looks something like this:

```
Special.search("some query", {
  :conditions => {:meal_tags => "dinner"} ,
  :geo => coordinates,
  :retry_stale => true,
  :with => {
    "@geodist" => 0.0..distance,
    :timeframe => [1,2],
  },
  :page => page, 
  :per_page => Kaminari.config.default_per_page,
  :order => "#{day} desc, @relevance DESC, @geodist ASC"
}
```

The errors I'm seeing are this:

```
Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'cuisine_taggings_specials.context' in 'where clause': SELECT `taggings`.`id` AS t0_r0, `taggings`.`tag_id` AS t0_r1, `taggings`.`taggable_id` AS t0_r2, `taggings`.`taggable_type` AS t0_r3, `taggings`.`tagger_id` AS t0_r4, `taggings`.`tagger_type` AS t0_r5, `taggings`.`context` AS t0_r6, `taggings`.`created_at` AS t0_r7, `tags`.`id` AS t1_r0, `tags`.`name` AS t1_r1 FROM `taggings` LEFT OUTER JOIN `tags` ON `tags`.`id` = `taggings`.`tag_id` WHERE `taggings`.`taggable_id` = 1 AND `taggings`.`taggable_type` = 'Special' AND (`cuisine_taggings_specials`.context = 'cuisines')
```

As you can see, the query is trying to locate the "cuisine_taggings_specials" table instead of just the taggings table.

I rebuild the indexes in both dev and test whenever I change the index.

Like I said, production and development work just fine, it's only when I'm running my tests.

Comment: What versions of TS and Rails are you using?

Comment: Thinking Sphinx: 2.0.5, Rails 3.2.1, Sphinx 2.0.3. This problem existed in Rails 3.1.x as well

Comment: Can you try TS 2.0.11? There were some fixes for acts-as-taggable-on in 2.0.8.

Comment: Thanks, Pat, but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wonder if it's related to polymorphic data not being populated when the test environment is generating the configuration. How are you running the tests? Cucumber, straight Capybara, or something else?

Once you've added some data, try regenerating the configuration and then indexing:

```
ThinkingSphinx::Test.stop  # if sphinx is already running?
ThinkingSphinx::Test.start # this generates config, indexes, and starts Sphinx.
```

Of course, this isn't helpful if the error's happening outside of your setup... Hence the first question :)

Comment: Pat, I'm using "ThinkingSphinx::Test.index *model.sphinx_index_names" in a Cucumber step a la your blog post. I tried the above. It still doesn't work.

Comment: Pat, I see the block of code dealing with the SQL rewrite in the association.rb file. Is there any reason why that wouldn't be executed in a Test environment?

Comment: `ThinkingSphinx::Text.index` won't rewrite the config file, and if it's polymorphic join, it's important that there's data there so ThinkingSphinx knows which tables it can join against. Hence running what I've outlined above.

Comment: Still getting the same results: Given /^there is a special "([^"]*)"$/ do |special_name|
  restaurant = Factory :restaurant
  Factory :special, :name => special_name, :restaurant => restaurant, :cuisine_list => "chinese, mexican", :meal_list => "dinner,lunch,happy_hour"
ThinkingSphinx::Test.stop  # if sphinx is already running?
ThinkingSphinx::Test.start
  step %(the Special indexes are processed)
end

Comment: It happens at the very end, when I "search" the database in the controller. The error is displayed in the browser.

Comment: I've just realised the error isn't from Sphinx... can you provide a stack trace?

Comment: Yeah, after thinking about why it might not be a TS problem I'm wondering if it's not a data problem. I'm going to try working that angle when I get a chance. If that doesn't work, I'll try and provide a dump. Regardless, I'll make sure you get the points.

Comment: I've tracked the problem down to a "destroy" action. This doesn't ahve anything to do with TS. It may have something to do with ActsAsTaggableOn. I really appreciate your help, Pat. I'll go ahead and accept this since you got me on the right track.